# why my reactjs router is giving me only a blank page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

i am a beginer reactjs programmer. while i was trying to learn react router from my video lectures i tried to implement it on my own but i got the following problem
i was trying to expermient latley with react router my code sounds logical but i still dont know why my page is empty?
App file :
`

```
import React from 'react';

import { Counter } from './features/counter/Counter';
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app"> 
    <h2>hello</h2>
    <Router>
      <>
       <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact>
          <h1>this is the homepage</h1>
        </Route>
       </Routes>
      </>
    </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index file:
`

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './app/store';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';

const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = createRoot(container);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
      
    </Router>
    
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`

i should at least get the code to work but still nothing shows up